# Does the Fedora installer not include default URLs for installation mirrors?

Tags: fedora, install

I installed Fedora 14 using a slightly non-standard method, i.e. loading the install media vmlinuz/initrd.img files via an existing grub2 instance. (I fetched them from a mirror).

The installer works fine, but I was a little bit surprised that after selecting the network install route I had to manually enter the URL of a FC14 mirror.

Luckily, I am having a secondary computer with network access available for looking up mirror URLs.

Does the FC14 not include any default install mirror urls? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is no, and this goes back to at least 2005, if you are doing this en-mass with grub, then you should still be able to specify in the boot options the paths to mirror, just like you can with specifying a path to a Kickstart file.

Some brilliant examples of how to do this can be found on the [Fedora Infrastructure wiki pages](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Kickstart_Infrastructure_SOP), mainly just `-x "method=<path to RPM directory"` should do the trick.